# Socket send and receive byte array

Tags: java, arrays, sockets

In server, I have send a byte array to client through Java socket

```
byte[] message = ... ;

DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
dout.write(message);
```

How can I receive this byte array from client?

Answer (score 71):

Try this, it's working for me.
**Sender:**

```
byte[] message = ...
Socket socket = ...
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

dOut.writeInt(message.length); // write length of the message
dOut.write(message);           // write the message
```

**Receiver:**

```
Socket socket = ...
DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

int length = dIn.readInt();                    // read length of incoming message
if(length>0) {
    byte[] message = new byte[length];
    dIn.readFully(message, 0, message.length); // read the message
}
```

Comment: dOut.writeInt(message.length); and dOut.write(message); is the winner. Thanks @franta

Answer (score 11):

First, do not use `DataOutputStream` unless it’s really necessary. Second:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("host", port);
OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
socketOutputStream.write(message);
```

Of course this lacks any error checking but this should get you going. The [JDK API Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html) is your friend and can help you a lot.

Comment: I don't see how this answers sending **and receiving** on the same socket.

Comment: why not to use DataOutputStream? is it adding some significant overhead?

Answer (score 2):

There is a JDK socket tutorial [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html), which covers both the server and client end. That looks exactly like what you want.

(from that tutorial) This sets up to read from an echo server:

```
    echoSocket = new Socket("taranis", 7);
    out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                echoSocket.getInputStream()));
```

taking a stream of bytes and converts to strings via the reader and using a default encoding (not advisable, normally).

Error handling and closing sockets/streams omitted from the above, but check the tutorial.

Comment: BufferedReader doesn't allow you to read input as a byte[] does it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either have the message be a fixed size, or you need to send the size or you need to use some separator characters.

This is the easiest case for a known size (100 bytes):

```
in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
byte[] message = new byte[100]; // the well known size
in.readFully(message);
```

In this case `DataInputStream` makes sense as it offers `readFully()`. If you don't use it, you need to loop yourself until the expected number of bytes is read.