# How to send image as bytes, and send json data together in the same HTTP request?

Tags: java, image, http, base64, transfer

I'm trying to send image as bytes because bandwidth is being killed by base64 strings. I've seen examples about transferring it as stream
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17573179/8359785 but the problem is that I'm not sure how to transfer json data with it at the same http request

Comment: Add a field in the `JSON` to accommodate the **image** `Bytes`.

Comment: How to do that when json can't handle binary data ,_, or am i missing something here?

Comment: Add your image `Byte[]` in the `JSON`

Comment: Use multipart?  One part for the Json and one part for the image.  I would try and provide some useful information/example code but I don't know what libraries you're using, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reduce the bandwidth usage to its maximum, just send data like this :

```
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dOut.writeInt(imageBytes.length); 
dOut.write(imageBytes);
dOut.writeInt(jsonBytes.length); 
dOut.write(jsonBytes);
```

Receive code:

```
DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int imageBytesLength = dIn.readInt();  
byte[] imageBytes= new byte[imageBytesLength];
dIn.readFully(imageBytes, 0, imageBytesLength); 
int jsonBytesLength = dIn.readInt();  
byte[] jsonBytes= new byte[jsonBytesLength ];
dIn.readFully(jsonBytesLength , 0, jsonBytesLength );
```

Comment: And how would the two things be received in the server? O.o

Comment: @BluEOS the OP asked for HTTP post but you gave answer for Socket?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field in the `JSON` to accommodate the `Byte[]` of your `Image`.

`JSON` could be like this:

```
{
    ...,

    "Image": [83, 97, 105, 102, 32, 115, 97, 121, 115, 32, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111],//Byte array of your image

    ...
}
```

Comment: That actually worked, didn't expect it to. Thanks a lot! I'll also try other solutions though to see which saves as much bandwidth as possible.

Comment: After testing the difference, this appears to use double the amount of bandwidth than when transferring base64.. But still, good to know that bytes can be included in json

Comment: I gave answer for **How to accommodate Byte in JSON** if you want to save bandwidth, there is a better of doing it.